# Long running processes on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, postgresql

My rails app ticks along quite nicely, however the deployment process can max out the memory & have some issues.

According to the server guys, there are 3 long running processes that are using up the memory & should be dealt with

```
Ruby processes: 
user@app-hippogo-production-6628:~$ ps -p 15892 -o etime= 1-20:00:43 
user@app-hippogo-production-6628:~$ ps -p 15903 -o etime= 1-20:00:52 
user@app-hippogo-production-6628:~$ ps -p 15925 -o etime= 1-20:01:07

Postgres process: 
user@app-hippogo-production-6628:~$ ps -p 14495 -o etime= 10-19:58:59
```

Should i somehow configure my app to close ruby & postgres processes? how can I do this? Some background info on what exactly is happening & should be happening would be appreciated.

UPDATE
The processes are using a total of 690mb of memory

i'm on rails 4.1.8 Ruby 2.2.5

I'm using thin as the server

I'm deploying to a ninefold server, they have their own sytem that deploys when you commit to the repo, a bit like heroku.  I believe it is chef based.

Answer (score 0):

We probably need a little more information to be helpful.

What version of ruby and rails are you running? What web server? What is a lot of memory? How are you deploying this rails app and to where (local, EC2, Heroku with Capistrano? Docker?)?

Comment: thx for the update.  I am not familiar with Thin and Ninefold but took a quick read.  Thin also may have some issues trapping signals that could leave processes running as well.  I would start by taking a look locally and determining what looks different.  If you start your app on your local machine (in as close to the Ninefold config settings as possible) do you see multiple processes and roughly what memory foot print do you see you locally? 690 MB across three processes isn't shocking, with some bad AR you can get you there pretty quick[issue](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/247)